# Safety of the input

Tags: voltage, ground

I have been shocked by a faulty piece of equipement (valve preamp) about 3 years ago. This kind of equipement use lethal voltage to run the valves (450VDC is common).

I want to protect myself

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHsZZj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the ground is connected to mains earth via the chassis. It should be safe if the equipement is connect to mains via a 3 prong, in house with a circuit breaker.

Still can I make the ground safer? (some technique less obvious than fuses in the supply)

Also is the simple RC filter enough to protect me from a lethal voltage that might eventualy be present in the conductor? After a fault/short circuit in the circuit.

Comment: According to your schematic, the _input_ is connected to the chassis, and earth is not. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: Chassis is connected to earth at the IEC plug. Input conuctor is not connected to chassis. The coax shield is connected to chassis. I could not find the junction symbol in circuitlab.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your context, but the description of the fault made me think of a residual-current device (RCD).

Comment: What’s better  shunt R across C or on either side to chassis?